Jsvector map cannot click on marker
I tried to create a world map with marker place on it.
But when I tried to OnMarkerClick it doesn't triggered the console.log why  ?
My Code:
<div id="worldMap" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>


Script:
@section('script')
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jsVectorMap JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsvectormap@1.3.0/dist/js/jsvectormap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- World Mercator Projection Map Data -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsvectormap@1.3.0/dist/maps/world-merc.js"></script>
   
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var myMap = new jsVectorMap({
                map: 'world_merc',
                selector: '#worldMap',
                markers: [{
                    coords: [48.8566, 2.3522],
                    name: 'Paris' // Marker in Paris
                }],
                markerStyle: {
                    initial: {
                        fill: '#F8E23B',
                        stroke: '#383f47'
                    }
                },
                onMarkerClick: function(event, index) {
                    console.log('Marker ' + myMap.markers[index].name + ' clicked!');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection


Make sure to use at least v1.5.0 in order for the onMarkerClick to work.
